# How to set a method that executes query in TypeORM?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

In pgAdmin (PostgresAdmin) I execute the following query:

```
SELECT category.name, subcategory.name
FROM category
JOIN category_subcategory ON category_subcategory.category_id = category.category_id
JOIN subcategory ON category_subcategory.subcategory_id = subcategory.subcategory_id
ORDER BY category.name, subcategory.name;
```

The table resulted after executing the query resembles everything correct, my aim was to establish a many-to-many relationship between category, subcategory and category_subcategory tables.

[image: pgAdmin Screenshot]

QUESTION

How can I resemble the same logic using TypeORM, so that the query is executed as soon as I start the backend server?

The tech stack that I am using is Nest.js, TypeORM, PostgreSQL

[image]

I tried entering the query in the code, however I get the following result

[image]

Comment: typeorm support raw query execution with entity-manager, check the documentation here: https://typeorm.io/entity-manager-api
but your question is not clear. you want to execute a specific function after starting the server??

Comment: if you want to call a function after the server started, onApplicationBootstrap() lifecycle is what you need in your case.
called once all modules have been initialized.